# How do I remove an orphaned Exchange 2010 server from the organization?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010

We properly uninstalled Exchange 2010 from a server but it is still appearing within the Exchange Management Console of the other Exchange 2010 server.  How can we remove this server from the Exchange organization?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to get your ADSIEDIT out...  Beware - you can break things - badly if you aren't careful.  Have a look at the ADSIEdit portions of this...

Got this from http://forums.msexchange.org/m_1800532154/mpage_1/key_/tm.htm#1800532154

```
You will have to open ADSIEDIT.MSC from one of your Domain Controllers and then navigate to the Server Name.

Path would be
Configuration -> Services -> Microsoft Exchange -> { Name of Your Organization } ->     Administrative Group -> Exchange Administrative Group -> Servers -> { Your Server Name } 

Then remove the Server and again try installing again.
```

It's really not as scary as it sounds...  Just be careful, you probably wanna back up your system state (AD) before you do this.

Comment: Thanks, Matt.  We actually found this already and it resolved our issue!

Comment: Happy to help.  :)