# Removing Offline Mailbox Server from Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010

Our DAG Exchange server went physically down, and I want to remove it from the Main Exchange Server, I was able to remove it from the DAG group, but can't find the way to remove it from Mailbox and client access list, please refer to the picture.

Many thanks for your help.

Image: http://postimg.org/image/twjgjxdev/

Answer (score 1):

DISCLAIMER:  Your environment is unique to you.  Carefully evaluate the following advice/links before diving right in.  Make sure you have good backups and know what you are doing.  Exchange isn't something to randomly run commands on...

See these links: [Remove a Failed Server DAG](http://exchangeserverpro.com/unable-remove-failed-server-dag-exchange-server-2010/) and here on SF: [How do I remove an orphaned Exchange 2010 server from the organization?](https://serverfault.com/questions/179600/how-do-i-remove-an-orphaned-exchange-2010-server-from-the-organization)

Since the first link is external to SF, here's the details on that one:

Remove the server that no longer works:

```
[PS] C:\>Remove-DatabaseAvailabilityGroupServer -Identity DAG -MailboxServer EX2 -ConfigurationOnly
```

Remove the failed server from the cluster:

```
[PS] C:\>Import-Module FailoverClusters
[PS] C:\>Get-ClusterNode EX2 | Remove-ClusterNode -Force
```

Then after these commands refer to the SF link again: [How do I remove an orphaned Exchange 2010 server from the organization?](https://serverfault.com/questions/179600/how-do-i-remove-an-orphaned-exchange-2010-server-from-the-organization)

That should take care of it.